# Image of an integer polynomial

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

How do I describe all integers that can be written in the form $$(x+y)^2+5x+3y$$ for some integers $x$ and $y$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can get all even integers by taking $y=-x$, and choosing $x$ appropriately.
2. You can't get any odd integers, because:
   a. $x,y$ both even: expression is even
   b. $x$ even, $y$ odd: odd+even+odd = even
   c. $x,y$ odd: even+odd+odd=even

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to rewrite it as $$(x+y)(x+y+3) + 2x.$$

This immediately shows us why every even number is possible, e.g. Vadim set $x+y = 0$, though we could also have $x+y+3 = 0$.

This also immediately shows us why every odd number is impossible, since both summands are even.